# Save logged in tenant in laravel lifecycle

Tags: laravel

I'm building a SaaS application and client can login with their assigned username based subdomain. Once they log in how to save that user data in service container so I can reference it further in requests.
How to store login session in database so I can terminate specific user session manually from super admin panel.
Thanks.

Comment: Your question is too broad... I really recommend you to search a little bit on Multi-tenancy with Laravel, also read the sources for laravel's auth driver to understand how it works.

Comment: I think your question can be reduced to _How to invalidate individual sessions on a per-user basis?_. Because if you know how to authenticate the user based on the subdomain he used, you should have all information of the subdomain authentication available within the session (or the linked user) anyway.